# Linux mv command failed

Tags: bash

I've been moving some directories, and got a permission denied where I would not have expected.

I'm not changing any permissions, it's just me on the machine, it's all the same filesystem, same owner and group throughout, not aware of any running process on this machine that could interfere. The only thing I can think of is that the "dir1" directory is a soft link on the same partition, but not sure how that would be an issue.

```
user:/dir1$ mv subdir ../dir2/
mv: cannot move 'subdir' to '../dir2/': Permission denied
```

As far as I'm concerned, that should have worked.

```
user:/dir1$ cd ..
user:/$ ls -lht
total 4K
drwxr-xr-x  2 user    user    4.0K Nov 30 11:48 dir2
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root    root      24 Oct 27 09:24 dir1 -> dir3
user:/$ mv dir1/subdir dir2
user:/$ ls dir2/ -lht
total 4K
drwxr-xr-x  7 user    user    4.0K Oct 20 16:28 subdir
```

Comment: Have you tried running with `sudo`?

Comment: I think the reason why you got a downvote is that someone thought you didn't even search for the error message. Also, the example `user@host:/directory/app/plugin` is unnecessarily cryptic.

Comment: @Verpous it wasn't permissions/sudo issue - see answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're in /directory/app/plugins (a soft link to /directory2/plugins), you're *referenced* to /directory2/plugins. You'll not see ../plugins.notworking/ from there.

If you run `ls ..`, you'll see /directory2/ instead of /directory/app.

One option, try this: `(cd -L .. && mv plugins/SomeSuperPlugin plugins.notworking/)` from `/directory/app/plugins`

Comment: I edited my question (tidied it up) so this now doesn't make sense with the stated directories, however the premise still applies - if you are in a softlinked directory, you are are effectively in the target, and not the source, so commands should be run as if they are in the target location. Or words to that effect.